# Change Background Color of Webpage Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a noob to Javascript so I am struggling with how to do this. I have to change the background color of my webpage when the user clicks on one of these three buttons. This is my code in the HTML.

```
 <li id ="yellow" ></li>

 <li id="orange" ></li>

 <li id="red" ></li>
```

So when the user clicks on those links the background color of the webpage needs to change to that color. What is the best way to do this with javascript?

I tried this

```
function changeBGC (color) {
document.bgColor= color;
}
```

and changed my html to this

```
 <li id ="yellow" onClick="changeBGC('yellow')" ></li>

 <li id="orange" onClick="changeBGC('orange')"></li>

 <li id="red" onClick="changeBGC('red')"></li>
```

Nothing happens when I click the links

Comment: Show us your attempt first.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the IDs of the elements are valid CSS colours, you can just read them from the attribute:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('li'), function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        document.body.style.background = el.id;
    })
});
```

Something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmUe2/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<ul id="colors">
    <li id="yellow">yello</li>
    <li id="orange">orange</li>
    <li id="red">red</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var colors = document.getElementById('colors');

colors.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var el = e.target,
       color = el.id;

    document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
});
```

That works... http://jsfiddle.net/Ayh3q/

Answer (score 0):

You may try this ([**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/23FNp/))

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="colorSet">
    <li>Yellow</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Red</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var ul = document.getElementById('colorSet');
    ul.onclick = function(e){
        var evt = e || window.event;
        var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = target.innerHTML;
    };
};
```