# Change the background color

Tags: javascript

I try to have a button like switch off and when the user clicks on it the button will change to a button for switch on and with this event the color of the whole page will change from the classic white to red.

How can I do it? Also it is possible to use one picture for on and off like this [one](http://pixabay.com/en/button-on-off-power-engage-energy-161555/) and when it is off have the first left part and when the user click on change and have the right part (blue) with only one image?

Here what I have until know with the buttons click

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="off.gif">

<p>Click the button to change the color.</p>

<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("on")) {
        image.src = "off.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "on.gif";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: change the image and simultaneously change the background color with this event.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797839/change-background-color-of-webpage-using-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @Evan: having *re-read* the linked question, yes: you seem to be right. I'm not sure, though, that the *answers* to that question are significantly better (I know, I remain biased). I leave it to others to argue on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place another line in each branch of the `if` and `else`, to update the `HTMLElement.style` of the `<html>` element (thereby changing the `background-color` of the whole page):

```html
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="off.gif">

<p>Click the button to change the color.</p>

<script>
  function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage'),
      // finding the root <html> element:
      page = document.querySelector('html');
    if (image.src.match("on")) {
      image.src = "off.gif";
      // setting the background-color of the <html> element
      // to white (#fff):
      page.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    } else {
      image.src = "on.gif";
      // setting the background-color of the <html> element
      // to red (#f00):
      page.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
    }
  }
</script>
```

I would, however, suggest binding your functionality - the event-handling function - in JavaScript, rather than using the in-line HTML event-handling attributes (`onchange`, `onclick`, etc), to allow for easier future-maintenance:

```js
function changeImage() {
  // caching the clicked image (the appropriate 'this'
  // is passed in by addEventListener() below):
  var image = this,
    // finding the root <html> element:
    page = document.querySelector('html');
  if (image.src.match("on")) {
    image.src = "off.gif";
    // setting the background-color of the <html> element
    // to white (#fff):
    page.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  } else {
    image.src = "on.gif";
    // setting the background-color of the <html> element
    // to red (#f00):
    page.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
  }
}

// finding the relevant element:
var button = document.getElementById('myImage');

// binding the event-handling function ( changeImage() ) to
// the click-event:
button.addEventListener('click', changeImage)
```

```html
<img id="myImage" src="off.gif">

<p>Click the button to change the color.</p>
```

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

Comment: Thank you very much for your very nice question it is like a lesson for me.

Comment: I'm very glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can handle this.  This example will show you both how you can handle the background color changes as well as change the button background using a single image as you requested.

CSS

```
.switched-on {
    background-color: red;
}
.switched-off {
    background-color: white;
}
.btn {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    color:white;
    background: url(http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/images/images.png) 0 0 no-repeat gray;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <button type="button" id="switchBtn" onclick="handleSwitch();" class="btn">Switch</button>
</body>
```

JS

```
function handleSwitch() {
            if (document.body.classList == '') {
                document.body.classList.add('switched-on');
                document.querySelector('#switchBtn').style.backgroundPosition = '-100px 0px';
                return;
            }
            if (document.body.classList.contains('switched-on')) {
                document.body.classList.remove('switched-on');
                document.body.classList.add('switched-off');
                document.querySelector('#switchBtn').style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
            } else {
                document.body.classList.remove('switched-off');
                document.body.classList.add('switched-on');
                document.querySelector('#switchBtn').style.backgroundPosition = '-100px 0px';
            }

        }
```

If you would like to test yourself here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/oee4mr8a/